# How can I access a specific property of HttpErrorResponse?

Tags: angular, http

I have the following HttpErrorResponse and I want to access the msg property. 
How can I access it as so I can print it out?

It comes from an http call that failed, I know the reasons it failed, but I want to print that out for the user.

[image: my HttpErrorResponse]

Comment: `response.error[0].msg`?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: @Phix this is it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is this you are trying to achiev.

```
this.yourHttpRequest().subscribe(
res => somethingOnSuccess, 
httpErrorResponse => {
   // here you have your object from HttpErrorResponse
   console.log(httpErrorResponse);
   console.log(httpErrorResponse.error[0].msg);
});
```